# Spacebar Actions - tools - in preferences is not working in Industry Compatible Key Maps

Tags: customization

I am using Blender 3.3 with custom keymaps based on the industrial compatible keymaps. I would like to define the space bar action to open "tools" and not play or search. In addition to that I can't access these preferences in my custom keymap and need to switch to standard Blender keymap to choose from the alternative options. After I have picked "tools" and go back to my keymap settings Blender will still perform the "search" action. Is this a bug, or am I doing something wrong?

Best regards and thanks for any help!
Tomas

Answer (score 0):

After spending hours in my keymap configurator I have found the solution. The "search" function and the "tool" function were both active in my keymap config. After deactivating the "search" function in my keymap, the "tool" function suddenly started working when I hit spacebar.